# autoClick at the same time error

Tags: javascript, html, push-notification

i create two button in index.html. The two buttons will function differently. I'm trying to give the autoclick function to both, but I get an error.

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
function autoClick(){
document.getElementById('linkToClick').click(); }
</script>

<script>
function autoClick(){
document.getElementById('linkToClick2').click();}
</script>
<head>

<body onload="setInterval('autoClick();',5000);">   
<button  type="" id="showNotifications" >
<a id="linkToClick" target="_blank" >Bildirim yolla</a>
</button>
</body>

<body onload="setInterval('autoClick();',1000);">   
<button  type="" id="showNotifications3" >
<a id="linkToClick2" target="_blank" >Bildirim</a>
</button>
</body>

</html>
```

The two buttons are sending notifications. Haven't problem. But they are auto clicking at the same time. Why "showNotifications3" button doing an autoclick in 5 seconds, not in 1 second?

Comment: This isn't a reproducible example as you have it here, but one thing to note is you're creating 2 methods with the same name. This won't work as you expect.

Comment: How to give two buttons "autoclick" function? Is not it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two js methods with same name. You can use something given below, Also I have removed two body tags.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function autoClick1(){
    // alert("1")
    document.getElementById('linkToClick').click(); 
}

function autoClick2(){
    // alert("2")
    document.getElementById('linkToClick2').click();
}
function callOnLoad(){
    setInterval('autoClick1();',5000);
    setInterval('autoClick2();',1000);
}
</script>
<head>

<body onload="Javascript: callOnLoad();">   
<button  type="" id="showNotifications" >
<a id="linkToClick" target="_blank" >Bildirim yolla</a>
</button>
<button  type="" id="showNotifications3" >
<a id="linkToClick2" target="_blank" >Bildirim</a>
</button>
</body>

</html>
```